# What was the penalty for failure to observe(Pe'ah) the law of gleaning?

Tags: law, deuteronomy, moses, leviticus

Several times the Israelites are cautioned to observe the law of gleaning which seemingly was a legally enforced entitlement of the poor.

Leviticus 19:9-10 NASB

> ‘Now when you reap the harvest of your land, you shall not reap to the very edges of your field, nor shall you gather the gleanings of your harvest. 10 And you shall not glean your vineyard, nor shall you gather the fallen grapes of your vineyard; you shall leave them for the needy and for the stranger. I am the Lord your God.

Leviticus 23:22 NASB

> ‘When you reap the harvest of your land, moreover, you shall not reap
> to the very edges of your field nor gather the gleaning of your
> harvest; you are to leave them for the needy and the stranger. I am
> the Lord your God.’”

Deuteronomy 24:19 NASB

> “When you reap your harvest in your field and forget a sheaf in the field, you are not to go back to get it; it shall belong to the stranger, the [n]orphan, and to the widow, in order that the Lord your God may bless you in all the work of your hands.

There seems to be no mention of the penalty for failure to observe this regulation

What was the penalty for failure to observe this regulation?

Answer (score 1):

Very few of the laws in the Torah had specific punishments associated with them.  Various of the tort laws sometimes did, but most did not.

However, we have the great passages of blessings and curses as follows:

- Blessings for obedience: Lev 25:-22, 26:1-13, and, Deut 28:1-14
- Curses for disobedience: Lev 26:14-39, and , Deut 28:15-68.

Thus, God promised both an incentive to obey, and disincentive to disobey.  Israel was promised prosperity for keeping the covenant and its law; and it was promised ruin and disaster for disobeying the covenant and its law.